# CSS rules for alignment in separate HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html, alignment

```css
html {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

body h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
}

body h3 {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.widget-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -47%);
}

.widget-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.widget-Gtitle {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.kpi-container {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
  border-spacing: 10px 1px;
  text-align: right;
}

.kpi-entry {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.kpi-value {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: right;
}

.kpi-Gvalue {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
}

.kpi-Glabel {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
}

.kpi-label {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: right;
}

.kpi-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
}

.green {
  background: #009c00;
}

.red {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.amber {
  background: #FFC200;
}

.arrowGreen {
  fill: #009c00;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.arrowRed {
  fill: #ff0000;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

  <ol id="error-list" class="error-list"></ol>
  <div id="widget-title" class="widget-Gtitle">EBIT Margin %</div>
  <div id="widget-container" class="widget-container">
    <table class="kpi-container">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="kpi-entry">
          <td>
            <div class="kpi-Glabel">Current</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="ragCurrentBox"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve" class="kpi-icon arrowGreen">
<g>
 <g>
  <path id="svgInternalID" d="M446.906,261.969c-1.792-3.656-5.5-5.969-9.573-5.969h-96V10.667C341.333,4.771,336.563,0,330.667,0H181.333    c-5.896,0-10.667,4.771-10.667,10.667V256h-96c-4.073,0-7.781,2.313-9.573,5.969c-1.792,3.646-1.354,8,1.135,11.219    l181.333,234.667c2.021,2.615,5.135,4.146,8.438,4.146s6.417-1.531,8.438-4.146l181.333-234.667    C448.26,269.969,448.698,265.615,446.906,261.969z"></path>
 </g>
</g>
</svg></div>
          </td>

          <td>
            <div id="valueCurrent" class="kpi-Gvalue">0.58%</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="kpi-entry">
          <td>
            <div class="kpi-Glabel">YTD</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="ragYTDBox"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve" class="kpi-icon arrowGreen">
<g>
 <g>
  <path id="svgInternalID" d="M446.906,261.969c-1.792-3.656-5.5-5.969-9.573-5.969h-96V10.667C341.333,4.771,336.563,0,330.667,0H181.333    c-5.896,0-10.667,4.771-10.667,10.667V256h-96c-4.073,0-7.781,2.313-9.573,5.969c-1.792,3.646-1.354,8,1.135,11.219    l181.333,234.667c2.021,2.615,5.135,4.146,8.438,4.146s6.417-1.531,8.438-4.146l181.333-234.667    C448.26,269.969,448.698,265.615,446.906,261.969z"></path>
 </g>
</g>

</svg></div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="valueYTD" class="kpi-Gvalue">0.57%</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am having an issue with two html5 widgets on the same page.
The alignment is off as you can see on both widgets for the subtitles Current and YTD.
[image]

Could anyone shed some light on this please, here are the CSS rules, they are both the same as they come from same css file. I would like the titles and arrows to line up perfectly even if the right units are a different length e.g 1 and £x.xx.
[image]

Comment: Always include relevant information (styles, in this case) **as text**. Better yet, for something like this, include a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I don't see anything in the pictured CSS that relates to the text in the widgets. But it looks like whatever the CSS is that relates to them is making them centered in their element, which they seem to be in both cases. We can't help you without more of the CSS, and without a much clearer idea of what end result you want.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have added a CSS snippet and added what I am looking to create, let me know if you need anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Will that text "Current" and "YTD" always be the same in all widgets? Then you can erase the `transform: translate` setting (at least the horizontal one)  and just adjust the "`left` setting with trial and error to find a satisfying position for left alignment. (left = approximately 35 - 40%)

Comment: @LaurenBuxton: When I run the snippet, I don't see anything at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I cant add my html as its all linked to AWS and you would be able to view it anyway...any ideas?

Comment: @Johannes I did this but it requires the css rules to be different, they all need to be the same, i have 16 widgets in total and I cant change the left alignment for each widget in the css file.

Comment: @LaurenBuxton: **Again:** [mcve] If you read it, you'll see what you're supposed to do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder have added more, i cant but two html 5 widgets in there but hope you can see the CSS and html for one

Comment: @LaurenBuxton: **Again: [mcve]** Look closely at each of those words (though I've always thought "verifiable" was and odd choice), and read closely the article they link to. People will be happy to help, but you have to do your end. That means putting in the work to make it **minimal** and **complete** while still **verifiable** (demonstrating the problem). The process usually means you find a solution for yourself, but if not, you have something reasonable to share to get help.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it now runs please see :) and I think this is what is you and others are after to help tackle the issue. I can't put two html files in one post so have just put the one in for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try changing it to:  display:inline;